# How to update TextClock?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to update my TextClock in an app I'm creating. Right now I have a button that subtracts an hour from the clock.(changes from 1pm to 12pm). My string that I'm updating seems fine but I have issues with the format.

Here is the code for updating:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh:mm:ss:a");

 public void changeTime(View v){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setTime(date);
    cal.setTime(newDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
    date+= -3600000;
    Date hourBehind = cal.getTime();
    String stringNewDate = sdf.format(hourBehind);
    Log.d("DateString: ", "String " +stringNewDate);
    dClock.setFormat12Hour(stringNewDate);



}
```

XML:

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/dClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:format12Hour="MMM dd yyyy \nhh:mm:ss:a"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Here is what my log.d displays: String Oct 08 2018
    12:02:07:PM

Here is an image of what happens to my clock:
[image]

Comment: post your sdf. and your textclock xml

Comment: @nupadhyaya updated.

Comment: What does your setFormat12Hour(String newDate) method do?

Comment: @WasabiTea it's a built in function to format the clock. Has the format that is shown in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

[setFormat12Hour](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html#setFormat12Hour(java.lang.CharSequence)) is used to set the format, which you have already done in your xml using `android:format12Hour="MMM dd yyyy \nhh:mm:ss:a"`.

You would need to call `setText` instead :

```
//dClock.setFormat12Hour("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:a");
dClock.setText(stringNewDate);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the format issues, but now it's now changing the text then immediately going back to the orginal text.

Comment: what is the original text?

Comment: Just the default time increasing thats given with TextClock.